# Broken link to blog

Tags: support, broken-link

A little while back, someone over on mechanics.SE referenced [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/) on meta.  However, the link appears to be broken.  Is there somewhere we could find a link to this post?

Comment: Maybe with [google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HF4CtWUKAdMJ:https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr&lr=lang_en%7Clang_fr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct link is https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/ (found via Google).

The broken link ends with `this-ones-big/`, the working link ends with `this-on/`. Perhaps not the best URL routing was used here by Stack Overflow.